# preguntas de contestación oral o contestación oral a las preguntas?

Tags: gramática

¿Me podrían confirmar si la expresión “[preguntas de contestación oral](https://dpej.rae.es/lema/sesi%C3%B3n-de-control#:%7E:text=Parl.,y%20comparecencias%20en%20su%20caso.)” es gramaticalmente correcta y su significado? Es que he buscado en Google y no ha salido ningún resultado con tal construcción gramatical. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

> Sesión de control
> Sesión plenaria o parte de la misma cuyo orden del día está compuesto
> de iniciativas de control a la acción del Gobierno, tales como
> **preguntas de contestación oral** al Gobierno, interpelaciones y
> comparecencias en su caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincido totalmente con la respuesta de RubioRic.

Lo que tal vez llama la atención de OP es que la contestación es posterior a la pregunta, pero hay muchas frases donde el modificador indirecto se refiere a una situación posterior a la descripta por el núcleo, por ej. asignaturas de aprobación automática (asignaturas cuya eventual aprobación será automática, asignaturas que se aprobarán en forma automática).

OP tal vez sintió que, al convertir el modificador indirecto en núcleo de la frase nominal, se reordena la secuencia temporal, pero esto cambiaría el foco:

- contestación oral a las preguntas (se contestan las preguntas que ya se hicieron)
- aprobación automática de las asignaturas (se aprueban las asignaturas que ya se cursaron)

Si deseamos referirnos a preguntas o asignaturas de determinado tipo, debemos decir:

- preguntas de contestación oral (preguntas cuya contestación será oral)
- asignaturas de aprobación automática (asignaturas cuya aprobación será automática)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias a todos por sus explicaciones! Ahora entiendo por qué la frase se construye de esta forma. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Has enlazado una página del Diccionario Panhispánico del Español Jurídico, respaldado por la Real Academia de la Lengua Española. Se sobreentiende que la gramaticalidad de los textos aportados es correcta.

Google además me muestra unos 1040 resultados para esa construcción, la mayoría pertenecientes a reglamentos de congresos, senados y asambleas legislativas de habla hispana.

**Preguntas de contestación oral** se refiere a que esas preguntas **deben ser contestadas oralmente** frente a otras que pueden responderse por escrito. El correspondiente gobierno de turno - ya sea municipal, autonómico o estatal - debe responder públicamente en un pleno de su cámara de **forma oral** a dichas preguntas.

Creo que la acepción de la preposición **de** empleada en este caso es

> 8. prep. U. para expresar la naturaleza, condición o cualidad de alguien o algo.